# Unknown publisher error while executing exe

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have deployed my windows app project but when i run it it first throws an error "Unknown publisher". How to hide this message?

Comment: Is it a warning or error, are you able to continue? Are you using ClickOnce or how do you deploy it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to digitally sign your package to prevent this type of error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms172240.aspx.

But typically it is advised not to worry about this at the development stage of the application but only consider this at the shipping time.

If you are interested in knowing the nitty-gritty details go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)