# How to sign executable

Tags: c, windows, executable, protected, windows-defender

Hi I just created a single c script and windows is saying "Windows Defended your computer" I tried to self sign my executable but it's still happening, if I want to share my programs how can I sign correctly my executable whitout windows saying everytime they protected the computer. Thanks!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World");
    getchar();
    printf("Bye");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown publisher error while executing exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503026/unknown-publisher-error-while-executing-exe)

Comment: Defender itself has a 'whitelist' which is local to your machine.  Have you considered added your program to that?

Comment: yes but me I dont care if this pop up on y screen its more if i share my script with other people

Comment: In that case you will need a code signing certificate issued by a trusted authority, which you will have to pay for.  I use Comodo.

Comment: Okok I will check that thanks!